# Question about ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE:

$\frac{dC(t)}{dt} = -\frac{3}{r_{p}}\cdot F\cdot k_{f}\cdot (C(t)-C_{p}(r,t))$

Where $C_{p}(r,t)$ is being solved by a PDE and $C_{p}(r,t=0) = 0$.

Is it correct to take $C_{p}(r,t)$ as a constant and write:

$C(t) = C_{p}(r,t) + C_{0}\cdot e^{(-\frac{3}{r_{p}}\cdot F\cdot k_{f}\cdot t)}$

?

This is the full problem:

[Full problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSSjB.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Well you can't write it as a constant since it varies with $t$. What is the PDE?

Comment: But if I solve the PDE corresponding to Cp(r,t) and I know its value at every time point, the above equation is not valid?

Comment: Well, if you've solved the PDE, just use the value $C_p(r,t)$ you found. Look, if you differentiate your solution with respect to $t$, you find the very first equation if and only if $\partial_t C_p(r,t) = -\frac{3}{r_p} k _f F C_p(r,t)$.